# Equal height for all column on each row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First of all i'm using bootstrap and jquery.
 So i'm trying to get first child class after all columns

```
var one = $(".col-x .some-class")
```

then i want to get the height of all `.some-class` height and check the tallest between them

what am in trying to achieve exactly :

1- get the tallest height between `.some-div` and make the others equal to the same height by adding top and bottom padding

2- i want to make this function for each row but each row should get the tallest height of `.some-class`

if you didn't understand me let me know to give you a code example.

here's the jsfiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Devel0per95/g2eo4n38/2/

Comment: I recommend to update with the code example...

Comment: @Shidersz here is the jsfiddle demo : https://jsfiddle.net/Devel0per95/g2eo4n38/2/ , i just want to make the items equal for every row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somthing like this: https://jsfiddle.net/g2eo4n38/4/ ?

```
function fixHeight() {
  // 1. Find the tallest element
  var tallest = 0
  $(".blog-item").each(function() {
    var height = $(this).height();
    if (height > tallest) {
        tallest = height;
    }
  });

  // 2. Adjust the height of the elements
  $(".blog-item").each(function() {
    $(this).height(tallest);
  });
}

fixHeight();
```

Another approach is using CSS grids, like this (then you don't have to use JS for styling, which is nice):

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.blog-item{
    background-color: #f6f7f7;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.blog-item .subtitle-item {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffbd1f;
}
.blog-item-title{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 30px
}
.blog-item-title h3{color: #333;}
.blog-item-title h3, .blog-item-title p {transition: 0.3s;}
.blog-item-title a:hover h3, .blog-item-title a:hover p {opacity: 0.6;}
.blog-item-body{margin-bottom: 15px;}

.blog-item-tags ul li{
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.blog-item-tags ul li:hover{
    background-color: #ffbd1f;
    color: #fff;
    border-color: #ffbd1f;
}
.blog-item a{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.blog-item a:hover {color: #ffbd1f;}
.blog-item a .fa{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px; 
}
.blog-item.featured{background-color: #ffbd1f;}
.blog-item.featured .blog-item-title p, .blog-item.featured .blog-item-title h3, .blog-item.featured p, .blog-item.featured a {
    color: #fff !important;
}
.blog-item.featured ul li {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color:#dda114;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="grid">
  <div class="blog-item bg featured">
    <div class="blog-item-title">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <p class="subtitle-item mb-5">Market Outlook</p>
        <h3 class="m-0">4Q 2018 Off-Grid And Mini-Grid Market Outlook</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-item-body">
      <p>Acquisitions, partnerships, and new technology capabilities
        dominated
        the microgrid news flow in the past few months. Project activity…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-item-tags">
      <ul>
        <li>Tag #1</li>
        <li>Tag #2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="content.html">Read more<i class="fa fa-angle-right ml-5"
                                       aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="blog-item">
    <div class="blog-item-title">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <p class="subtitle-item mb-5">Insight</p>
        <h3 class="m-0">Distributed Energy in Emerging Markets</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-item-body">
      <p>Advances in distributed technologies at the frontiers of today’s
        energy
        system can now provide power where the traditional grid is…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-item-tags">
      <ul>
        <li>Tag #1</li>
        <li>Tag #2</li>
        <li>Tag #3</li>
        <li>Tag #4</li>
        <li>Tag #5</li>
        <li>Tag #6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="content.html">Read more<i class="fa fa-angle-right ml-5"
                                       aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="blog-item">
    <div class="blog-item-title">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <p class="subtitle-item mb-5">Insight</p>
        <h3 class="m-0">Clean Energy And The Paris Promises</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-item-body">
      <p>The 2015 Paris Agreement saw virtually every nation on earth pledge
        to
        address the threat of climate change. Each country’s Nationally…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-item-tags">
      <ul>
        <li>Tag #1</li>
        <li>Tag #2</li>
        <li>Tag #3</li>
        <li>Tag #4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="content.html">Read more<i class="fa fa-angle-right ml-5"
                                       aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that's useful i will add edit and more script, thanks for the help anyway :)